# Chrome extension - Showing hidden div on button click problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to show a hidden div by changing the CSS display attribute from none to block when I click a button. This is working fine in the browser itself but when testing it as an extension, the button doesn't do anything. I'm not sure what I'm missing when it comes to the difference between coding a regular website and an extension in this instance.

index.html (relevant code only)

```
    <div class="rankingsbtn-wrapper">
        <button type="button" class="rankings-btn" onclick="openRankings()">View Rankings</button>
    </div>
    <div class="rankings-div" id="rankings-div">
```

style.css

```
.rankings-div {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 25px;
    width: 85%;
    height: 85%;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Fantasy Trade Analyzer",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Extension used to check fantasy football trades",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    }
}
```

trade.js

```
function openRankings(){
    document.getElementById("rankings-div").style.display = "block";
}
```